# React-Redux update part of the state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following initial state for my `react-redux`

```
const initialState = {
    logged: false,
    user: null,
    company: null,
}
```

When I first login, I set the state data

```
const data = action.payload.data;
const properties = action.payload.properties;
const notifications = action.payload.notifications;
return {
    ...state,
    logged: true,
    user: {
        id: data.UserID,
        firstName: data.UserFName,
        lastName: data.UserLName,
        email: data.UserEmail,
        securityLevel: parseInt(data.SecurityLevelID),
        notifications: {
            multiProp: notifications.MultiProp && parseInt(notifications.MultiProp) === 1 ? false : true
        }
    },
    company: {
        id: data.CompanyID,
        name: data.CompanyName,
        email: data.ContactEmail,
        leadSource: parseInt(data.LeadSourceCompanyID)
    }
}
```

Then, at some point of my project, I need to update only `user.notifications.multiProp`, so I created a new Type called UPDMULTIPROP and I'm doing:

```
case Types.UPDMULTIPROP:
    const userData = action.payload.data;
    return {
        ...state,
        user: {
            notifications: {
                multiProp: userData.notifications.MultiProp && parseInt(userData.notifications.MultiProp) === 1 ? false : true,
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it set all the other user state to undefined. How can I update just the `multiProp`?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the exact content of the modules you're using instead of code-snippets. It would be helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user is also an object, to keep user state the same you should also spread the user.

```
case Types.UPDMULTIPROP:
  const userData = action.payload.data;
  return {
    ...state,
    user: {
      ...state.user,
      notifications: {
        multiProp: userData.notifications.MultiProp && parseInt(userData.notifications.MultiProp) === 1 ? false : true,
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To update nested object immutably you need to spread it again. Like

`user : { ...state.user, notifications : someValue }`

Like this.